# dotnet core how to get AllowAnonymous route on custom authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I have a requirement where I need to check if current MVC application have `SSO` cookie, and if it is not present I need  redirect user back to sign in page, however if request is coming towards `AllowAnonymous` endpoint I should bypass this requirement and proceed with a call.

I am unable to use `httpContext.GetEndpoint()` in my middleware since it is already written application and nothing is configured via `UseEndpoints` method. I was thinking to implement `AuthenticationHandler`, but that does not give me access to `ActionDescriptor`. After little more looking I found that I can implement `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` and decorate my `Controller` or `Action` with this and I will have access to `ActionDescriptor` where I will have access to read Attributes and detect `AllowAnonymous`. This seems to be a solution however, I am unable to locate when this action filter gets triggered, isit been triggered at the same level as any other action attributes and by that time `UseAuthentication` and `UserAuthorization` already executed?

Where do I implement such requirement? to short circuit request if `SSO` Cookie is not present but allow to proceed if `AllowAnonymous` attribute is present.

Comment: You can get the AllowAnonymous attribute declared on action in custom ActionFilter.

Comment: @Rena, the problem with this approach is that it will by pass the authorization pipeline, I will have to allow access even tough I should not and after I get into action filer pipeline will check authorization again. Seems like not proper approach to me. unless I am missing something